# In stm32f , the RTC is written in the backup registers in which frequency?

Tags: stm32, stm32f4discovery, stm32f4

We know that the RTC will erase its data when there is no power , So we use the backup registers to store the data. But in which frequency is this RTC's value written in the backup register? RTC works in the frequency of 32khz but at what frequency the value needs to be written? please find me an answer

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work that way.

As long as the Vbat power supply is there, the backup registers are preserved, **and** the RTC is running. If there is no Vbat (battery empty or removed), then the RTC as well as the backup registers are lost.

If you want to have permanent storage when there is no Vbat, then use the internal flash.